# config file does not exist for rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new to ROS and trying to work with rviz. When I run rviz using following command

```
rosrun rviz rviz
```

I get following error prompt (on a window)

> Config file does not exist

> /home/abc/.rviz/display_config does not exist!

Can any one help me please? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70165/config-file-does-not-exist-for-rviz/) by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS Fuerte and earlier, this message is normal to come up the first time you launch RViz.

After RViz has come up, select File / Save Config and it should disappear next time run RViz.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on 2013-08-01**:
Thanks. It works :)